# Im using React Router and I want one of my route links with path="/" to be the home page on reload.. How can you do that?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
   {
  "homepage": ".",
  "name": "sanid",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },


  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I understand that using React-Router puts all the routes in the component App.js which is the root component that renders this nested routes. The thing is that I want one of this nested routes to be the root component when you open the page. How can I do it? thnks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the redirect function from react-router-dom !!

```
  <Redirect to="/" component={Inicio} />
```

It looks like this!

```
<Router>
      <Redirect to="/" component={Inicio} />
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Inicio} />
          <Route path="/Desinfecciones" component={Desinfecciones} />
          <Route path="/Matafuegos" component={Productos} />
          <Route path="/OtrosServicios" component={OtrosServicios} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
```